# Form inserting data duplicate times from all users

Tags: php, mysql, insert, records

I can't figure out why, but whenever a user makes a post on the site I am working on it will post to the database multiple times, 1 entry for each member on the site(currently 3).

Here is my code.

**Add_topic.php**

```
$category=$_POST['category'];
$sub_category=$_POST['sub_category'];
$topic_data=$_POST['topic_data'];
$posted=date("h:i:s d/m/Y"); //create date time

$sql = "INSERT INTO `topics`(category, sub_category, topic_data, posted_by, posted)VALUES('$category', '$sub_category', '$topic_data', '".$_SESSION['user_id']."', '$posted')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result){
header("Location: topics.php?category=$category&sub_category=$sub_category");
exit();
}
```

**Topics.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, topics.topic_id, topics.category, topics.sub_category, 
topics.topic_data, topics.posted_by, topics.posted, topics.view, topics.reply 
FROM users, topics WHERE topics.category = '" . $_GET['category'] . "' AND  topics.sub_category = '" . $_GET['sub_category'] . "' ORDER BY topics.posted DESC";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
```

Comment: How is the form posted? this is possibly where the problem lays

Comment: Is there actually 3 posts in your table, or is it just displaying 3 posts in Topics.php?

Comment: Is it posting once for each user and the user_id for each is different or once for each user and the same user_id each time? It sounds like the way `add_topic.php` is being called has problems.

Comment: Is the code in `add_topic.php` in a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `add_topic.php` is inserting multiple rows. You can verify this by looking directly at your table.

I believe your issue is your query in `Topics.php`.

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, topics.topic_id,
               topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, 
               topics.posted_by, topics.posted, topics.view, topics.reply 
        FROM users, topics 
        WHERE topics.category = '" . $_GET['category'] . "' 
        AND  topics.sub_category = '" . $_GET['sub_category'] . "' 
        ORDER BY topics.posted DESC";
```

You are doing a join on `users` and `topics`, but you are not defining what links them. So it is creating a row for each user to each topic post.

You can see it as the 1st example result set at this SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dfc4/4

What you want to do is `LEFT JOIN` users to topics `ON topics.posted_by = users.user_id`.

That is the 2nd example result set at - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7dfc4/4

So your query would now be (escaping your `$_GET` to prevent SQL Injection) -

```
$sql = "SELECT users.user_id, users.username, users.profile, topics.topic_id,
               topics.category, topics.sub_category, topics.topic_data, 
               topics.posted_by, topics.posted, topics.view, topics.reply 
        FROM topics
        LEFT JOIN users
        ON topics.posted_by = users.user_id
        WHERE topics.category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['category']) . "' 
        AND  topics.sub_category = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sub_category']) . "' 
        ORDER BY topics.posted DESC";
```

note - you should not be using `mysql_*` functions in new code. It is depreciated as of php v.5.5. You should update your code to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: thank you, upon rechecking you were right and it was NOT duplicating records, just displaying them that way, I am currently learning via tutorials etc, mysql ones are the easiest to find but I am planning on convering to mysqli when closer to completion.